# How do I define a `NewType` that's subscriptable, like `List[int]`

Tags: python-3.x, typing

I've tried things like `NewType['SomeType', (SomeClass, typing.Container)]`, and it doesn't work.

Suppose I have a class that's really simple, as follows.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

Now I want to annotate a function that returns this type as `NewA[int]`, i.e. using `__getitem__`, which I obviously haven't defined in `A` above, but it adds an extra layer of description. Is this possible? And if not, is there a reason I shouldn't try to do something like this?

Comment: This may be possible using: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types but I haven't used that before.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I just tried it and surprisingly, it works. I never would have tried using Generic (and never would have guessed that this was the way to accomplish this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use `Generic`, as defined in the standard library's `typing` documentation.

Comment: If I want to make a Stack that's just a thin layer over a List, without having to reimplement all the List methods, would that be possible with this method?

Comment: @mic Yes, by also using normal inheritance.  `class Foo[T](list): pass` in python 3.12, or `T = TypeVar("T"); class Foo(list, Generic[T]): pass`